# polynomial equation $x^6+2x^5-5x^4+9x^3-5x^2+2x+1=0$ in terms of radicals

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

The task is to solve $$x^6+2x^5-5x^4+9x^3-5x^2+2x+1=0$$ by radicals. A hint is given to put $$u=t+1/t.$$ I tried factoring the polynomial and applying the rational root theorem, none gave me direction. 
I also don't know how to apply the hint.

Any suggestion or help will be very much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480102/quadratic-substitution-question-applying-substitution-p-x-frac1x-to-2x4x  and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/403025/equation-with-high-exponents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: the polynomial is [self-reciprocal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_polynomial#Palindromic_and_antipalindromic_polynomials) (or palindromic) and $x=0$ is obviously not a root, so divide by $x^3$ and regroup to get:

$$x^3 + \frac{1}{x^3} +2\left(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)-5\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)+9=0$$

Let $u = x + \frac{1}{x}$ so that $x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2} = u^2 - 2$ and $x^3+\frac{1}{x^3} = u^3 - 3u$ then the equation reduces to the cubic in $u$:

$$u^3+2 u^2 - 8 u + 5 = 0$$

which factors as:

$$(u-1)(u^2+3u-5)= 0$$

Each of the $3$ roots in $u$ gives a quadratic in $x$ to solve for the total of $6$ roots in $x$.

Comment: Thank you. This is the first time I heard about palindromic polynomials...

Comment: So, this gives me the following roots: $$\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2},$$ $$\frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2},$$ $$\frac{-3+\sqrt{29}+\sqrt{22-6\sqrt{29}}}{4},$$ $$\frac{-3+\sqrt{29}-\sqrt{22-6\sqrt{29}}}{4},$$ $$\frac{-3-\sqrt{29}+\sqrt{22+6\sqrt{29}}}{4},$$ $$\frac{-3-\sqrt{29}-\sqrt{22+6\sqrt{29}}}{4},$$ Hence, the given polynomial is solvable by radicals.

Comment: @desperatemuch Those look right, except you should write $\sqrt{22-6\sqrt{29}}=\,i\,\sqrt{6\sqrt{29}-22}$

Comment: Why does it matter? I'm confused.

Comment: @desperatemuch It's not *critical* in this particular case, but it's good practice for several reasons. **(1)** It's customary to make it obvious which roots are real vs. complex. **(2)** The square root of a *positive* number is understood as the plain radical virtually everywhere, while negative (or complex) values under the radical may introduce ambiguities depending on context, see for example [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487509/general-misconception-about-sqrt-x) or [that](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/990394/square-root-and-principal-square-root-confusion).

Comment: @desperatemuch  **(3)** For roots of higher order, the *value* may depend on the interpretation, see for example [Why do I get an imaginary result for the cube root of a negative number?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1602160/why-do-i-get-an-imaginary-result-for-the-cube-root-of-a-negative-number).

Comment: @dixv So this implies that the splitting field for the given polynomial is $$\mathbb{Q}\left(i\sqrt{3},\sqrt{29}, i\sqrt{6\sqrt{29}-22},\sqrt{6\sqrt{29}+22}\right),$$ right?

Comment: Don't know that it follows *directly* from the factorization. Guess you could check online with [Magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/) or [Sage](https://cloud.sagemath.com/settings), but that's not my favorite cup of tea.