# Solving $\lim_{x\to 0}(\frac1x)(\frac1{\sqrt{1+x^{-2}}})$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I'm trying to solve $\lim_{x\to 0-}(\frac1x)(\frac1{\sqrt{1+x^{-2}}})$ and $\lim_{x\to 0+}(\frac1x)(\frac1{\sqrt{1+x^{-2}}})$.

I've graphed the function so I do know that their respective values are -1 and 1, but I can't find these answers by simplifying and calculating no matter how hard I try. I guess the function could be transformed into $\frac{{{(1+\frac1{x^{2}}}})^{1/2}}{x}$, but I'm not sure if it's useful.

Can anyone help? Keep in mind that I'm not allowed to use L'Hopital.

Thank you.

Comment: For the second one the “limand“ is equal to $$\frac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$ for the first one substitute $y=-x$.

Comment: I don't really understand how to arrive to these two conclusions and why they're valid.

Comment: I am using that if $x,y\ge 0$ then $$x \sqrt y = \sqrt{x^2y}.$$

Comment: Also, what does "limand" mean?

Comment: The term in the limit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{1}{x \sqrt {1+\dfrac{1}{x^2}}}=\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]{|x|}}{x \sqrt {x^2+1}}$$
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}=\dfrac{x}{x \sqrt {x^2+1}}=1$$
$$\lim_{x \to 0^-}=\dfrac{-x}{x \sqrt {x^2+1}}=-1$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/486681/is-sqrtx2-always-pm-x